# My images in assets folder not replaced after update app in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have some images in the assets folder, I change all images with new images but with the same name. when I update my app the old images are still shown. I must clear data to see the new images in my android app.

Comment: Try invalidate cache and restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old images are cached by android studio and you must clear the cache.
for doing this go to `Files > Invalidate Cache/Restart`
or you can clean the build files by: `Build > Clean Project`.

Comment: The problem is still if I install apk as a new all thing is right but when I install on the previous version the previous images are shown.
if I make clear data the new images will display.
its because the name of images in assets file is the same previous.